# Parsing table with Beautifulsoup (index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse all World of Warcraft player on my server with Wowprogress and Beautifulsoup with this code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os

    adresse="http://www.wowprogress.com/gearscore/eu/hyjal/char_rating/next/0#char_rating"

page=urlopen(adresse)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)

# print (soup.prettify)
all_tables=soup.find_all("table")

bonne_table=soup.find("table",class_="rating ")

place_liste=[]
pseudo=[]
guilde=[]
ilevel=[]

for row in bonne_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    print(cells)
    place_liste.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
     pseudo.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
     guilde.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
     ilevel.append(cells[3].find(text=True))

 print(pseudo)
 print(guilde)
 print(ilevel)

os.system("pause")
```

And I receive an error

```
place_liste.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

And I don't understand ==> There is 4 "item" per row but it gave me this error. I clearly don't understand why it says it's out of range.

Comment: You're kind of assuming in advance that there -will- be 4 'cells'. How sure are you of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First row has no `<td>`. It has header `<th>` instead.

Implement some conditional check

```
if len(cells) >= 4:
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly but can it create trouble if a td is empty (like a player without guild) ?